# jQuery: avoid checking if the key pressed is 'enter' everytime

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code below, instead of using on keydown, is there a way I can use on e.which === 13 where the keydown is? This was it wont have to check each time a key is pressed, and will work only when enter is pressed.

**Current Code**

```
$('.search').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.which === 13) {
        // enter key pressed
        var value = this.value; // this is the inputs value
        console.log(value);
    }
});
```

**What I hope to do (pseudo code)**

```
$('.search').(when key === 13 is pressed) { // Only if the enter key pressed

        // enter key pressed
        var value = this.value; // this is the inputs value
        console.log(value);
    }
});
```

Can something like this be done?

Comment: $.on takes 1 2 or 3 arguments, and first one must be event name, so the answer would be No

Comment: No, there is no event fired just for hitting the enter key.

Comment: I don't think so, you can't attach events conditionally.

Comment: I dont need the on. I can forgo that. Any other way to then?

Comment: No.  The first snippet of code is how you do it.  If there were a way to say `.on("enter")` (for example) it would also have to check every keypress in order to work.

Comment: Clarification: is this about performance or about code cleaning?

Comment: @RenatoZannon Performance :-) Why detect every key pressed?

Comment: @Norman because that's what the browser exposes to you. In my experience, these checks are extremely fast, and hardly a performance bottleneck. I suggest profiling your code before trying to optimize it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a higher-order function to extract that logic for you:

```
function onlyOnEnter(fn) {
  return function(e) {
    if(e.which === 13) {
      fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
$('.search').on('keydown', onlyOnEnter(function(e) {
    var value = this.value; // this is the inputs value
    console.log(value);
  })
);
```

That way, your callback function will only be called when the key pressed is an enter.

Comment: But it still has to check every keypress, so it's exactly the same as the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, `onlyOnEnter` is reusable between multiple callbacks.

Comment: He's looking for an event handler for *just* the enter key, so he doesn't have to check the value of every keypress.  It simply can't be done.

Comment: @RenatoZannon he's saying you basically just reorganized the code. The guy is looking for an event that fires ONLY on enter key being pressed, rather than testing for enter key anytime a key is pressed (presumably for performance reasons).  Of course that is not actually possible, which is what the true answer to this question is.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but I thought this was exactly about code organization. If it is about performance or something else, then it needs to be stated on the question

Comment: He wasn't very clear about it you're right. I took the line "that way it won't have to check every time a key is pressed" to imply it was about performance.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

The best you can do is capturing events (you are using `on` but it could be any other event capturing method). There are many different kind of events (mouse events, keyboard events, control specific events, etc.), you have to look at the event, since each event type will have different properties.

For key pressing, there are some events available for capturing such as `keypress`, `keydown` and `keyup`. You can't expect that one specific key will have an event on its own because you want so save one line of code.

Comment: I can forgo the on. It's not really needed. Any other way then?

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't really possible (at least not for the purposes of your code) nor does it make a lot of sense.  The `keydown` event is fired whenever a key is pressed.

Whether you are manually checking to see if it's the enter key or whether the browser or jQuery is doing it internally isn't tremendously relevant - regardless the browser will need to check which key was pressed any time any key is pressed to test whether it was the enter key.

Essentially you're wasting your time.  There isn't going to be any measurable performance optimization by trying to do this.  No matter how you try to detect the enter key being pressed, it will be tested for every `keydown` or `keypress` event regardless of which key is pressed.